# get columns values from list

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have returned list from web service  to java script which contains only one row , and i should loop on it to get each column value . i have tried this code but, there s no value .

```
function draw_Result(content)
{
    alert(content.length); // gives "1"
    if (content.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {

            var Name = content[i].Name;
            alert(Name);

        }
    }
}
```

any help

Comment: Does the alert show correct length of list?

Comment: Can you show the `content`? Without that, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: the first alert returns the right value"1". the problem is how to get value of Name column

Comment: i want to get columns values of this row.... how????

Comment: Please do `alert(JSON.stringify(content))` instead of `alert(content.length)` and post the results

Comment: this alert is right , there is one row , i am talking about the second alert

Comment: We are all here to help you. And to help you we need to know what is in `content`. So if you would like to get a solution, it's necessary to follow the tips from the other users.

Comment: my alert(content) returns 1 but the second alert returns "undefinded"

Comment: And what does `alert(JSON.stringify(content))` return?

Comment: I'm stunned that after 20 mins, the OP still hasn't shown the content of `content`. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of object.  If it's returning a JavaScript object, you can iterate through all the members as described on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).  Try this for testing:

```
for (var prop in content) {
    alert(prop + " = " + content[prop]);
  }
```

So a JavaScript object acts as a dictionary when using a for loop; using for iterates through each "key" of the object, and using `obj[prop]` returns the actual value the object has.  This only works if you are dealing with an object, but if you have JSON you can use JSON.parse to parse a JSON string into an object.

Comment: length can be called on most objects,  and is always integer; I don't see now parseInt helps...

Answer (score 0):

try this, context.length is return string value, You need convert to int that

```
    function draw_Result(content)
    {
        alert(content.length); // gives "1"
        if (content.length > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < **parseInt(content.length); i++)** {

                var Name = content[i].Name;
                alert(Name);

            }
        }
}
```

See this line

```
for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(content.length); i++) {
```

Comment: you don't need to parse the `length` value using `parseInt()` OP is already getting that.

Comment: "Undefined" alse. can i use data table in java script? how can i do this

Comment: @user3261588: what is the content that you are passing it to the javascript.

Comment: i am passing bigint as Id to retrieve details in one row

Comment: @user3261588: can you show us your code how you are passing the data to the `draw_Result()` function

Comment: function mona(Id)
        {
            Adimin_Service.WebService.SelectTeacher_byIDs(Id, draw_Result, Failed);